# How to use nested for loops while reading data from Firebase (using Java)?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Firebase for the database of my Android application. I need to look at all triplets of people in my database and assign a score to each group, so I can find the group with the greatest score. So what I had in mind was something like this pseudocode:

```
for person1 in People {
    for person2 in People{
        for person3 in People{
            if(calculateScore(person1, person2, person3)>score){
                score = calculateScore(person1, person2, person3);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So my code is like this:

```
peopleRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


        for (DataSnapshot childDataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

            Log.d("TAG", "1st loop");

            peopleRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


                    for (DataSnapshot childDataSnapshot2 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                        Log.d("TAG", "2nd loop");

                        peopleRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


                                for (DataSnapshot childDataSnapshot3 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                                    Log.d("TAG", "3rd loop");

                                    int score = calculateScore(childDataSnapshot1, childDataSnapshot2, childDataSnapshot3);
                                    if(score > bestScore){
                                        bestScore = score;
                                    }

                                }

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                            }
                        }

                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            }

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
}
```

The problem is, the order of execution gets mixed up. I want it to be something like 1 2 333333333 2 333333333 2 33333333 1 2 33333333 2 333333... but it prints something like 1111 2222222222222 33333333...

I know Firebase is asynchronous, but I thought it should work since I call everything in onDataChange in a nested manner. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

`ValueEventListener()` returns all the data under any database reference node. So it is useless to call the same listener on the same node recursively.

Once all the data is loaded you can use for loop to store all the objects and compare them in the memory.

```
for (DataSnapshot childDataSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
    // parse person snapshot
    // add to list
}

// then compare with for loop
// int score = calculateScore(person1, person2, person3);
```

Comment: What if I need to use 3 different database references? For example, I need to calculate a score for a triplet consisting of a person, a movie, and a book. Should I still load it to a list? Wouldn't it get too heavy for the memory?

Answer (score 0):

Using nested loops when getting data from a Firebase database does not guarantee you have a result as the order of your loops. This is happening because each `onDataChange()` method within your loops has its asynchronous behaviour, so nesting those those loops doesn't solve the order of execution.

Unfortunately, you cannot know when getting the data from the database is completed in order to call a second loop. This is happening because Firebase is a realtime database and getting data might never complete. That's why is named a realtime database because in any moment the database can be changed, item can be added or deleted.